# Why json hijacking can be prevented using POST method?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, security, csrf

I came across the following ASP.NET MVC error, when returning `json` in a `Get` method:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Apparently this vulnerability is called **json Hijacking**. [This article](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) explains that a website could be exploited when returning `json` using `Get`. But returning `json` in a `Post` method is safe.

Why changing `Get` to `Post` prevents this attack?

Comment: After reading the article, I would like to know if we set correctly CORS in the server and the cookie domain correctly if it's still an issue

Comment: From the article, it looks like the exploit uses a `<script src="">` tag to fool the browser into requesting JSON from the server. Since `script src` always uses GET, the exploit fails if the server doesn't respond to GET. Therefore, POST should be safe.

Comment: Yes, you can issue a POST request from a script, but this specific exploit won't work unless the server responds to GET requests.

Comment: No, the `<script src>` tag fools the browser into downloading a JSON array from the target server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was really surprised to see that so many people is trying to prove that **JSON Hijacking** is still a security issue. (Of course it is if you still use Firefox 2, Opera 9, or Safari 3). None of the modern browsers have this issue for a long time. The article you referred in your question is written in 2009. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers) for more information about how the issue was fixed. And you do not need to worry about `JsonRequestBehavior` just allow get and forget.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I have not read the bounty question. Why changing request to post prevents json hijacking?

You can find a article [here](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/json-hijacking-demystified/), that describes the JSON Hijacking attack steps. It goes as follow:

- **Step 1**: Get an authenticated user to visit a malicious page.
- **Step 2**: The malicious page will try and access sensitive data from the application that the user is logged into.This can be done by embedding a script tag in an HTML page **since the same-origin policy does not apply to script tags**.

  `<script src="http://<jsonsite>/json_server.php"></script>`

  The browser will make a GET request to json_server.php and any authentication cookies of the user will be sent along with the request.

  **...**

You can think this scenario like that, user visits `www.yoursite.com` and get authenticated. After that user leaved your site and go to a malicious site. If the malicious site has a `<script src="http://www.yoursite.com/some_endpoint"></script>` tag, browser will make a GET request. If returned data is a JSON that site can get the sensitive data by object prototype setter. (Remember attackers will try to use SCRIPT tag not an AJAX request because same-origin policy does not apply to script tags. See [Cross-origin network access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access) rules.)

But if you change the request type of the `http://www.yoursite.com/some_endpoint` from `GET` to `POST`, when the browser tries to access it, your server will reject it.

Also i am leaving a old MVC Framework book [here](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=7ZOXKItbQC4C&pg=PA552&lpg=PA552&dq=script+tag+only+get+request&source=bl&ots=GyvUjK4868&sig=ACfU3U0signoi7Eem5inu55658MDw-h1lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYlKqXrOjpAhUDxqYKHdvBBPEQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=script%20tag%20only%20get%20request&f=false) that explains concept.

Answer (score 4):

Having the request as a `POST` will prevent any request coming form other domains based on [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) unless you configure your server to allow it, which turns this issue to another thing. `GET` requests on the other hand are allowed by browsers to retrieve resources, like javascript that might have sensitive data from your domain and it happen to be an array not an object.

**Updated answer**:

You will not actually find a source tells you how `GET`, `POST` requests are different for `JSON Hijacking` attacks. The difference actually is how web servers and browsers are dealing with those requests. JSON hijacking vulnerability is about  malicious websites using an endpoint in your website/app that provides JSON data and response to a `GET` request (**a request that by default allow resources, e.g js, images, text files to be  download**), if you change it to `POST`, they will not be able to include `<script>` that do a `POST` request from the `src` attribute, even inside the script tag `POST` requests will be prevented by CORS policy.

In the modern browser era we no longer have this type of vulnerability **(at least in the form mentioned in the discovery article by Jeremiah Grossman)** because of CORS policy.

This also referenced in other [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452925/what-sensitive-information-could-be-disclosed-when-setting-jsonrequestbehavior#answer-21499008)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read the article that you have include... I am not able to find where it describes how `Get` and `Post` methods are treated differently using CORS policy... are you able to point it out please?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini, I meant to refer to CORS page as a reference for what CORS is, not as a page that refer to the difference between `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... as stated in the bounty, I am looking for an **reputable source** to clarify why `Post`and `Get` behave differently with respect to json hijacking. I appreciate your explanation that this is because of CORS policy, but I was not able to find how/why CORS policy is different for `Get` and `Post` in the document.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini You didn't state anything about a reputable source in your question. You just asked "why".

Comment: @thelr the OP mentioned that in the blue box above, not in the question.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini, I finally had time to update my answer, please check it and hope it will answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the network panel on any webpage that contains scripts, images, stylesheets or fonts you will see that all those requests are done using `GET` HTTP method. For example this is how a request for a file loaded by a `<script>` tag looks like:

[image: An example of a GET request for a JavaScript file]

And this is an example for an file loaded by an `<img>` tag looks like:

[image: An example of a GET request for an image]

Browser will just blindly trust you that if you are loading such a resource from anywhere you know what you are doing and it will fetch it for you (otherwise things like CDN would not work) **as opposed to an XHR request**!

XHR requests (including `fetch` calls) are checked against CORS policy, I believe you are familiar with what that is. JavaScript will not be able to make any XHR request for a resource that lives on a different domain (or port etc.).

So you have two types of request policies:

1. Anything you fetch using XHR will be checked against CORS but you can pick whatever HTTP request method you want
2. Anything you load using `img`, `script`, `link` etc will not be checked against CORS policy **but you are restricted to `GET` HTTP requests only**. The browser will also send all the cookies along, most importantly the authentication ones in this case.

That means that if you are serving a JSON array using `GET` you can use a `script` tag to fetch it for you **no matter which domain you are on**. Then, using the trick mentioned in the article, you can *execute* the array (sounds weird but yes) and grab the sensitive information.

If you'd be using `POST`, the attacker has no way of using a `script` (or any other) tag to perform this request since they use `GET` requests to fetch resources.

You could think *Ah but I can use `form` to do that!* but you will run into the same CORS issues. If you just submit a `form`, the JSON data will load into the current page and there is no way for you as an attacker to get it since your script no longer exists on the page.

You could think *Ah I just set the `form` target to an `iframe`!* but JavaScript will not allow you to access anything within that `iframe`.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

JSON shouldn't be returned as `GET` because the data can be stolen with an injected `<script>` from an attacker (for example, if dynamic content is loaded without being HTML escaped). Scripts are requested from the server via the `GET` method, so anything sent from the server with `POST` won't be ran from an injected script. With their script being ran, the hacker can use your logged in cookie to access your JSON, which they shouldn't be allowed to get.

Read more about JSON hacking vulnerabilities in [this article](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/json-hijacking-demystified/) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174986/8804293).