# Show loader while POSTING an image from one page to another

Tags: php, post, base64, loader

i am POSTING an image from one page to another , the src of the image is "data:image/png;base64" .

While posting the page keeps loading ; is there a way to show a loader while data is being POSTED ?

Comment: You might try to post it with AJAX like with jQuery. Is POST required?

Comment: Not sure about that. Let me try jquery post and see if it fulfills the achievement. Thanks for reminding me @Jask

Comment: @Jask - Even if POST is required, it can still be sent via AJAX. Can't it?

Comment: @Stanyer Yes, it can, there is a question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877309/submit-cross-domain-ajax-post-request

Comment: @Jask I wasn't aware this question was regarding cross-domain posting

Comment: @Stanyer I made assumption that it is.

Comment: Ah okay, I presumed that because he said one page to another it was on the same domain (might be wrong) which is why I thought a jQuery AJAX call was pretty self explanatory. @Ekram if it is on the same domain, a simple jQuery AJAX call with the type of POST would be sufficient, where you show a loading symbol on `beforeSend` and hide the loading symbol on `success` and `error`, or `complete`.